# Remove all files with given extension from GIT history

Tags: git

I realised my repository is bloated with large WAV files. I would like to strip them from the repository, including the history and all branches. Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `git filter-branch` with an `--index-filter` that uses `git rm --cached` to eradicate any traces of the waves.

Comment: Hi @Vampire ! Thanks for your help. I am aware of the fact that history includes HEAD; I am editing the answer to make it clearer. If it isn't too much trouble, could you please give a complete command? Thanks!

Comment: Should be something like `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -- **/*.wav' --all` I think

Comment: It's more something like `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch **/*.wav" HEAD`